# Insert data from temp table into existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a query to pull and manipulate data from a source table, the query then adds this to a temporary table. A separate query then used the data from the temporary table and created a new table.

The source table has now been updated with new rows and I will need to add the new roles to my table. However I am unsure how I will update my existing table in this situation rather than creating a new one. Here is my code:

```
select ID, Date, 
rtrim(ltrim(replace(AccountNumber,'AccountNumber: ',''))) 'AccountNumber',
replace(MPAN,'MPAN: ','') 'MPAN',
replace(MSN,'MeterSerialNumber: ','') 'MSN',
replace(ReadingDate,'ReadingDate: ','') 'ReadingDate',
replace(RegisterID1,'RegisterID1: ','') 'RegisterID1',
replace(Reading1,'Reading1: ','') 'Reading1',
replace(RegisterID2,'RegisterID2: ','') 'RegisterID2',
replace(Reading2,'Reading2: ','') 'Reading2',
Status
INTO [NEW TABLE]
FROM #TEMPTABLE
Order by date desc
drop table #TEMPTABLE
```

I'm wondering if it is as simple as running this query again using 'INSERT INTO [TABLE]' to update the existing table, but I'm not sure and haven't found anything online that gives me a clear answer for my situation.

This was the first table I have created myself and this will be the first time I use a query to update an existing table. So I'm a little apprehensive about making changes when I'm unsure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The key here is making sure that you can match previously created records with the new ones on your new temporary table. We use primary keys here (or any combination of columns that can identify unmistakably all rows). Then just do an `UPDATE` by joining the temporary one with the physical one through these columns. If you have new records you will also need an `INSERT` (or even `DELETE`). The `MERGE` operation can do everything in one go.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to do, but `INSERT INTO` is used to create a new table, not update an existing one.

Comment: I have three tables [SOURCE], [TEMP], [NEW]. My query was used to manipulate data from [SOURCE] into [TEMP] and then [TEMP] into [NEW]. The existing data in [NEW] hasn't changed, but new rows have been added to [SOURCE] (think this is where I wasn't clear in my original question). So I need to go through the process again and then add the new rows to [NEW].

Answer (score 0):

Hope you're enjoying working in the Elecricity Industry.

If I understand correct you have a source [Table], then a #TempTable.

You are pulling data from [Table] and manipulating it, then you want to put this back into [Table]. This should just be done via an UPDATE statement, to best do this get the primary key from [Table].

```
--Get your Temporary Data
SELECT 
ID,
MPAN,
MSN,
--etc...
INTO #TEMPTABLE
FROM [Table]

--DO your data manipulation
UPDATE #TEMPTABLE
SET MSN = LTRIM(RTRIM(MSN)) --Or whatever your actions are

--Show that your changes have been applied correctly
SELECT * FROM #TEMPTABLE


--apply values back to source table
UPDATE org 
SET org.MPAN = tmp.MPAN,
    org.MSN = tmp.MSN
FROM #TEMPTABLE tmp
INNER JOIN [Table] org ON org.ID = tmp.ID
```

EDIT: I noticed you were saying how would you handle this if the source data had changed, i.e the data in [Table]. In this case you would do the update in reverse, so you would update #TEMPTABLE with values from [Table] - if the field names are identical this should be difficult.

EDIT2: If you are apprehensive about updating your source table, you might want to look into TRANSACTIONS in SQL Server. You can perform some SQL, see your changes then rollback anything you've done to the state of data at the start of your transaction.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE ID = 12 --Still there
DELETE FROM [TABLE] WHERE ID = 12 --Example
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE ID = 12 --No longer there

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 

SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE ID = 12 --Still there
```

And when you're happy with your update, set ROLLBACK TRANSACTION to COMMIT TRANSACTION

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't think I explained myself correctly. I have three tables [SOURCE], [TEMP], [NEW]. My query was used to manipulate data from [SOURCE] into [TEMP] and then [TEMP] into [NEW]. The existing data in [NEW] hasn't changed, but new rows have been added to [SOURCE] (think this is where I wasn't clear in my original question). So I need to go through the process again and then add the new rows to [NEW]. I hope that's better.

Comment: Providing that all 3 have the same primary key field this should be an issue. 

If [NEW] does not exist then you could do another SELECT INTO query FROM [TEMP]

Comment: I think I am almost there. After running [TEMP] I have tried using 'INSERT INTO [NEW] SELECT (column1, column2, etc) FROM [TEMP]'. However this has duplicated the data that already existed in [NEW]. Is there a way to add just the new rows into [NEW] without also re-adding the existing ones?

Comment: LEFT JOIN onto the new table via the primary key, anywhere where [NEW].[ID] IS NULL doesn't exist in the target table, and this is what you should use for your insert select statement

Answer (score 0):

consider using MERGE, it's either updating existing rows, inserting new rows from source that yet not exists on the target table, or even do something if there are rows from target table but not exists on the source table

```
MERGE <target_table> [AS TARGET]
USING <table_source> [AS SOURCE]
ON <search_condition> --For example ColumnSource = ColumnTable
WHEN MATCHED --Rows already exist
   THEN UPDATE target_table SET ... --Do Update for example
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET --Rows not exist on Target Table
   THEN INSERT(...) VALUES(...) --Do Insert for example
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE --Rows not exist on Source table but exists on Target Table
   THEN DELETE ... --Do Delete for example
```